# How to get a list as parameter of a function in haskell using GHCi

Tags: list, haskell

I'm starting to learn `Haskell` now in college and I need to make anything in haskell. I tried to generate a random number but it seems too complicated. So I think I'll do something with `lists` but I can't make it work when trying to pass a list as parameter. I tried something like:

```
teste x[] = x
```

Just to receive a list and print it but I get some erros. What's the correct way to pass list as parameter ?

Also: Any ideia what I could implement? Just an example a little toy programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify the type of the parameters of a function, you use `::`. You can make a function that takes a list and returns a list by saying

```
teste :: [a] -> [a]
teste x = x
```

Comment: Hey man, is it possible to make a list receive the return of a `filter` ? like:  `let logins = [...]` now I want to make logins become the result of a `filter` where elements with lenght < 8. Is it possible ? ( I know how to filter the lenght) but cant make logins receive the result

Comment: Just write `let logins = filter (\x -> length x < 8)`. However, Haskell is a functional language and its paradigm is very different from iterative languages: You do not typically define steps in the order in which they must be processed (e.g.: "Sort this list, then take the elements with length 8, then..."); instead you compose functions to obtain your desired results.